How the send logs from NodeJS to Datadog without using Datadog Agent
I'm looking for a solution to send logs from a Node.js application to Datadog without relying on the Datadog Agent (Which needs to be installed in machine).
Are there alternative integration methods or libraries available for achieving this? I want to ensure seamless log monitoring and analysis within Datadog while avoiding the use of the Datadog Agent due to specific constraints or preferences.

This works for NodeJs and Typescript and JS
You require two packages

https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston
https://www.npmjs.com/package/datadog-winston

Coding
npm i --save winston
npm install --save datadog-winston

logger.ts File
import * as winston from 'winston'
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
var DatadogWinston = require('datadog-winston')
dotenv.config();

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'debug',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
})

logger.add(
  new DatadogWinston({
    apiKey: process.env.DATADOG_APIKEY,
    hostname: process.env.DATADOG_HOSTNAME,
    service: process.env.DATADOG_SERVICE,
    ddsource: process.env.DATADOG_DD_SOURCE,
    ddtags: process.env.DATADOG_DD_TAGS,
  })
)

export default logger

ENV File
   DATADOG_APIKEY=super_secret_datadog_api_key
   DATADOG_HOSTNAME=my_machine
   DATADOG_SERVICE=super_service
   DATADOG_DD_SOURCE=nodejs
   DATADOG_DD_TAGS=foo:bar,boo:baz

any_index.ts
import logger from "./logger";


logger.error("YOUR ERROR")
logger.info("YOUR INFO")


